# Export to DataGrid To Excel in WPf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want export to datagrid to wpf but when export an error is generated

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in solutions.exe

my code...

```
    Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();

        excel.Visible = true; 
        Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
        Worksheet sheet1 = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
        Range range;
        Range myRange;
        for (int i = 1; i < dgDatos.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
             range = (Range)sheet1.Cells[1, i + 1];
            sheet1.Cells[1, i + 1].Font.Bold = true;
            range.Value = dgDatos.Columns[i].Header;

            for (int j = 0; j < dgDatos.Items.Count; j++)
            {
                TextBlock b = dgDatos.Columns[i].GetCellContent(dgDatos.Items[j]) as TextBlock;
                 myRange = sheet1.Cells[j + 2, i + 1];
                myRange.Value = b.Text;
            }
        }
```

}

Comment: Which line does the error point to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without giving any indication of where the null value is, my bet would be on

```
myRange.Value = b.Text;
```

When you do this:

```
TextBlock b = dgDatos.Columns[i].GetCellContent(dgDatos.Items[j]) as TextBlock;
```

... `b` will be null if the object assigned to that cell is not a `TextBlock`.

For that matter, why have a `TextBlock` in the `DataGrid`?  Check out `DataTable`.